# Text overflowing out of button instead of moving to the next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create an HTML button which opens a link. It looks like a small title and some short description. But whenever the description is too large, it overflows out of the button.

I'm using bootstrap and jquery.

Code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container-fluid" style="text-align : center">
  <div id="final">
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <button class='btn btn-info btn-block'>
          <b>
            <p>
              Heading which is okay
            </p>
          </b>
          <p>
            And this is some really really very long text which is not fitting inside my button tag and is overflowing out of the button. But this text is meant to be a small description of the heading. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi auctor iaculis enim eu ultrices. Pellentesque nec hendrerit mauris.
          </p>
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="search-result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**What I've already tried**

```
p { // Truncating instead of moving to the next line
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Or

```
btn {
  // This is not working
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or

```
p {
  // Also not working
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

I've tried searching Stack Overflow and found two suggestions:

- Applying `overflow: hidden;` but it is truncating the text instead of continuing it to the next line.
- Applying `display: inline-block;` but I am not able to get it working.

Comment: word-break:break-all;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the bootstrap applies `white-space: nowrap` to all the `.btn` class to wrap the button text in a single line...

So you will need to change this to `white-space: normal` by using a parent selector of yours so that it won't affect on all other buttons.

Also ***Element p not allowed as child of element button in this context***..So better to use `<br>` instead of `<p>` if you want text on next line

Also ***The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element***...so use `btn btn-info btn-block` classes on `<a>` and remove `button`

```
#final .btn{
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

#final .btn {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container-fluid" style="text-align : center">
  <div id="final">
    <div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
        <b>Heading which is okay</b><br> And this is some really really very long text which is not fitting inside my button tag and is overflowing out of the button. But this text is meant to be a small description of the heading. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi auctor iaculis enim eu ultrices. Pellentesque nec hendrerit mauris.
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="search-result"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```